# ST_ Intersects vs ST_DWithin behavior on polygons using PostGIS

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql, performance

I have a large table with millions of current and historical building footprint polygons and need to efficiently fetch all of these that fall fully or partially within a user specified set of search areas polygons of arbitrary shapes and sizes like city or state boundaries.

I am aware of spatial indexing and partitioning, but for this question I am simply wondering wether there’s any major difference between using `ST_Intersects()` or `ST_DWithin()` methods when queried on polygon inputs this way:

```sql
SELECT * FROM search_areas JOIN building_footprints
ON ST_Intersects(search_areas.geom, building_footprints.geom);
```

Versus:

```sql
SELECT * FROM search_areas JOIN building_footprints
ON ST_DWithin(search_areas.geom, building_footprints.geom, 0);  -- zero distance
```

It is not clear from the [documentation](http://postgis.net/workshops/postgis-intro/spatial_relationships.html) or from my `EXPLAIN` tests if both forms are logically equivalent or even if one is faster than the other.

Comment: I think there needs to be more context for this question. What is the applied use case?

Comment: Added a bit more context to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`ST_Intersects(a, b)` and `ST_DWithin(a, b, 0)` are logically equivalent.  They should also be practically equivalent.  However, they have very different implementations, and it is possible that there are some obscure differences for a few cases, due to numerical precision issues.  If you find otherwise, please file a PostGIS ticket.

As for performance, in all/most cases `ST_Intersects` will be faster.  This is because it includes an internal cached optimization step, which significantly improves performance in joins involving many rows.